# Issues getting networking working Packer VSphere-ISO Centos 7

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, packer

While new to Packer and Kickstart scripts, I am trying to automate the setup of CentOS 7 (eventually 8) boxes in a VSphere cluster. My Packer code is calling a Kickstart script to complete the setup, but running into issues getting networking working. As each node in the ESX cluster is 6.5.X, I see the Guest IP hack isn't required.

When I run "packer build --debug" with PACLOG=1 for more verbosity, I see my code fails to complete the .Waiting for IP..." step:

```
==> vsphere-iso: Adding generated Floppy...
==> vsphere-iso: Set boot order...
==> vsphere-iso: Power on VM...
==> vsphere-iso: Waiting 10s for boot...
==> vsphere-iso: Typing boot command...
2020/06/09 18:40:15 packer-builder-vsphere-iso plugin: Special code '<esc>' found, replacing with: CodeEscape
2020/06/09 18:40:15 packer-builder-vsphere-iso plugin: Waiting 1 second
2020/06/09 18:40:20 packer-builder-vsphere-iso plugin: Special code '<enter>' found, replacing with: CodeReturnEnter
2020/06/09 18:40:20 packer-builder-vsphere-iso plugin: Waiting 1 second
2020/06/09 18:40:21 packer-builder-vsphere-iso plugin: [INFO] Waiting for IP, up to total timeout: 30m0s, settle timeout: 5s
==> vsphere-iso: Waiting for IP...
==> vsphere-iso: Post "https://<server name>.com/sdk": EOF
==> vsphere-iso: Step "StepWaitForIp" failed
```

Running the installer with or without a GUI installer in the VM, I see that Networking is not configured in the VM(adapter is up but no IP). As the adapter name is not consistent, I am trying to let Packer use any connected adapters, and use DHCP to ease mass deployments. I have tried "network --onboot yes --device=link --activate" and "network --onboot yes --activate" as well as other combinations. Each time a file is created under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/, but network is still not established.

I replaced all variables in my Packer JSON with the hard-coded variables, but get the same results.

As validation I also can see the temporary VM listed as a VM belonging to the network in VSphere, and it has a valid MAC.

I have also tried to ensure that the open-vm-tools package is installed, but it did not help.

Has anyone ran across this issue?

Builders section from packer file:

```
   "builders": [
      {
      "type": "vsphere-iso",

      "vcenter_server": "{{user `vsphere-server`}}",
      "username": "{{user `vsphere-user`}}",
      "password": "{{user `vsphere-password`}}",
      "insecure_connection": "true",

      "datacenter": "{{user `vsphere-datacenter`}}",
      "cluster": "{{user `vsphere-cluster`}}",
      "network": "{{user `vsphere-network`}}",
      "host": "{{user `vsphere-host`}}",
      "datastore": "{{user `vsphere-datastore`}}",

      "vm_name": "{{user `vm-name`}}",
      "notes": "Build via Packer",
      "guest_os_type": "centos7_64Guest",

      "boot_wait": "10s",
      "boot_order": "disk,cdrom,floppy",

      "communicator": "ssh",
      "ssh_username": "root",
      "ssh_password": "server",

      "CPUs": "{{user `vm-cpu-num`}}",
      "RAM": "{{user `vm-mem-size`}}",
      "RAM_reserve_all": false,
      "disk_controller_type": "pvscsi",
      "disk_size": "{{user `vm-disk-size`}}",
      "disk_thin_provisioned": true,
      "network_card": "vmxnet3",

      "convert_to_template": true,

      "iso_urls": ["{{user `iso-url`}}"],
      "iso_checksum": "{{user `iso-checksum`}}",
      "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `iso-checksum-type`}}",
      "floppy_files": ["ks.cfg"],
      "boot_command": [
        "<esc><wait>",
        "linux inst.text ks=hd:fd0:/ks.cfg<enter><wait>"
```

KS.cfg:

````
```# Install a fresh new system (optional)
install

# Specify installation method to use for installation
# To use a different one comment out the 'url' one below, update
# the selected choice with proper options & un-comment it
cdrom

# Set language to use during installation and the default language to use on the installed system (required)
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Set system keyboard type / layout (required)
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'

firstboot --disable
# Configure network information for target system and activate network devices in the installer environment (optional)
# --onboot  enable device at a boot time
# --device  device to be activated and / or configured with the network command
# --bootproto   method to obtain networking configuration for device (default dhcp)
# --noipv6  disable IPv6 on this device
network --onboot yes --bootproto dhcp --noipv6
#network --bootproto=dhcp --onboot=yes --device=link --noipv6 --activate

# Set the system's root password (required)
# Plaintext password is: server
rootpw --iscrypted $6$rhel6usgcb$aS6oPGXcPKp3OtFArSrhRwu6sN8q2.yEGY7AIwDOQd23YCtiz9c5mXbid1BzX9bmXTEZi.hCzTEXFosVBI5ng0

# Configure firewall settings for the system (optional)
# --enabled reject incoming connections that are not in response to outbound requests
# --ssh     allow sshd service through the firewall
# firewall --enabled --ssh
firewall --disabled

# Set up the authentication options for the system (required)
# --enableshadow    enable shadowed passwords by default
# --passalgo        hash / crypt algorithm for new passwords
# See the manual page for authconfig for a complete list of possible options.
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512

# State of SELinux on the installed system (optional)
# Defaults to enforcing
selinux --permissive

# Set the system time zone (required)
timezone --utc America/Chicago

# Specify how the bootloader should be installed (required)
# Plaintext password is: password
bootloader --location=mbr --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet" --password=$6$rhel6usgcb$kOzIfC4zLbuo3ECp1er99NRYikN419wxYMmons8Vm/37Qtg0T8aB9dKxHwqapz8wWAFu
autopart --type=lvm

# Initialize all disks

clearpart --linux --initlabel

services --enabled=NetworkManager,sshd
# Packages selection
%packages --ignoremissing
Require @Base
@Base
@minimal

# End of %packages section

%post
#sudo yum upgrade -y
yum -y install open-vm-tools
yum -y install sudo
systemctl enable vmtoolsd
systemctl start vmtoolsd
systemctl enable sshd
systemctl start sshd
%end

# Reboot after the installation is complete (optional)
# --eject   attempt to eject CD or DVD media before rebooting
reboot --eject
````